# Can we use native code as plugin in Rhomobile?

Tags: android, rhomobile

I need to run a java code for Android inside Rhomobile app. Is there any way i can call the java code. I have seen some of the plugins to interact with native codes for Android.

I tried searching and i did get to this url http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhoconnect/plugin-intro.
But i guess this is not for Rhomobile if i'm not wrong.

I have a library file for my requirement. Is there any way i can use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Have a look at this http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/extensions#native-extensions

The link you get is for RhoConnect ( basically meant for sync operation). You need to look into the native extension for Android : [Rewriting the Generated Native Extension Source Code for Android](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/extensions#rewriting-the-generated-native-extension-source-code-for-android)

If you need some more help and support, you can go over

https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/‎

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rhomobile

You can also simply post you query here and tag `Rhomobile` & `Rhodes`.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will need some more help if i face some more issue over here.

Comment: Need you help over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798878/how-to-pass-variables-to-partial-in-rhomobile