# How to pass variables to partial in Rhomobile

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I have a partial where i need show the value of variable `catchedEvent`,

**Partial**

```
<div class="eventList">Here to show the value of the variable</div>
```

On my erb page i'm calling this using

```
<%= render :partial =>"mypartial" %>
```

I can't get the way to pass the variable to it. Please help.

Comment: You can set the values to instance variable and can directly use it in the partial

Comment: Will those value be available over there ? I mean where do i need to set the value in erb or controller.

Comment: Yes just set the value in controller and use it inside partial as like you do in you view page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the locals or collections as specified over here http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/ui#advanced-usage-of-render

```
<%= render :partial =>"mypartial", :locals => { :event => "myevent" } %>
```

Then on partial, use it like

```
<div class="eventList"><%= event %></div>
```

Second, if you assign some value to the instance variable in the controller,

```
@event = "myevent"
```

then you can directly access it inside the partial as below,

```
<div class="eventList"><%= @event %></div>
```

These are some of the ways you can use to pass the variables.